# Maior numero primo

Tags: python, revisão-de-código

Poderiam me ajudar com meu código? Eu estou tentando fazer o programa imprimir o maior numero primo dos quais o usuário digitou, porém o meu programa ta imprimindo o maior de TODOS e não o maior primo. eis o código.

```
def primo(numero):     
   if (numero == 1):
       return False

   
   for d in range(2,(int)(numero/2)+1):
    
       if (numero % d == 0):
        return False
       
   else:
    return True

c = maior = 0   
while True:
   numero = int(input())
   if numero == 404:
       break
   if primo(numero):
       c += primo(numero)
   else:
       c -= primo(numero)
   if c == 1:
       maior = (numero)
   else:
       if (numero) > maior:
           maior = (numero)
      
       
if c > 0:
   print(f'{maior}')
else:
   print('SEM PRIMOS')
```

Comment: Não seria mais simples só fazer uma condição que se for primo e maior que o valor `maior` então definisse o número como maior? Algo como `if primo(numero) and numero > maior: maior = numero`. Não entendi porque você tentou contar a quantidade de primos informada.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique inicialmente se um numero é primo, isso é feito no segundo if dentro do while, e caso sea primo incremente a quantidadede primos `c`, verifique se esse numero primo é maior do que o `maior` caso seja entao `maior` recebe o `numero`.

Pelos prints você acompanhar essa troca de valores. Se `c` for maior do que 0 então existe pelo menos um numero primo

```
def primo(numero):
    
  if (numero == 1):
      return False 
  for d in range(2,(int)(numero/2)+1):  
      if (numero % d == 0):
        return False    
  return True

c = maior = 0   
while True:
  numero = int(input())
  if numero == 404:
      break
  if primo(numero):
      print('é primo '+str(numero))
      c += primo(numero)
      if numero > maior:
        maior = (numero)
        print('maior '+str(maior))      
      
if c > 0:
  print(f'{maior}')
else:
  print('SEM PRIMOS')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sabendo que:

- ***f(x) = 2x + 1 | x ∈ N*** é a função no conjunto dos números naturais que definem os números impares.
- `range(0)` é uma sequência vazia.
- A expresão `[identificador ":="] expressão` é uma [expressão de atribuição](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions)(vide [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#id9)).
- A expresão `x if C else y` é uma [expressão condicional](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).
- O código abaixo não faz testes de validação para entrada do usuário.
- O operador `//` é a divisão para o número inteiro mais próximo(Vide [Floor Division](https://docs.python.org/3.9/glossary.html#term-floor-division)).

É possível simplificar o seu algoritmo tornado-o mais eficiente e mais legível:

```py
def primo(n):     
  #Testa n para saber se é 1 ou par diferente de 2...
  if n == 1 or (n != 2 and n % 2 == 0):                  
    return False                             #...caso seja uma ou ambas as condições retorna False. 
  #x percorre o intervalo [0, n/4[ no conjunto do números naturais...
  for x in range(n // 4):
    #...testa o n para saber se é divisível por um ímpar...
    if n % 2*x+1 == 0:
      return False                           #...se sim retorna False.
  return True                                #Passado em todos o testes retorna True.

c = False                                    #Flag que indica e se houve a entrada de um primo pelo usuário.
m = 0                                        #Declara o maior número.
while True:    
   #Testa a entrada n para saber se é 404...
   if (n:= int(input())) == 404:
       break                                 #...se n for 404 abandona o laço.
   #Testa se n é maior que m e se é primo, indicando ou não a entrada dum numero primo pelo usuário.
   if n > m and (c:= primo(n) or c):
     m = n                                   #...se sim a ambas a condições m recebe n.
      
print(f'{m}' if c else 'SEM PRIMOS')
```

<sup>Tete o código no [repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/primos#main.py)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pegar o números e adiciona-los a uma lista chamada numbers, depois para exibir o maior valor primo é so fazer asisim:
`print(max(int(number) for number in numbers if number % 2 !=0))`